# A word for unobtrusive architecture amidst architecturally superior ensemble?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a term for unobtrusive architecture amidst architecturally superior ensemble. E.g., a contemporary building in a college campus or in a European old town that features some stylized elements and color of the old buildings, but is generally bland and deliberately "un-architectural," purely functional building. It tries to blend in and not to rival with the original architecture.

Sentence: In the 1950s, the university leadership sought to expand the old campus with modernist buildings, but after a severe public backlash, they opted for a conservative solution, settling on typical ___ architecture/buildings for good. [or something similar]

Comment: 'Bland' might be appropriate.

Comment: I could see getting some of the sentiment across with "infill" although 'infill development' means something different (usually tearing down smaller buildings and replacing them with larger ones) .  I'm not really sure it would be fair to call it "typical infill" either because many such buildings are of very high design quality. "Utility focused" ?

Comment: **filler** might work. It's not used in architecture, but is used in the sense you mentioned when talking about writing or merchandize displays.

Comment: Thank you all. I would add that these buildings are not always purely utilitarian and could even feature some architectural innovations, but these are usually deliberately hidden (e.g. in courtyards or interiors) and try not to challenge the more important buildings

Comment: You could try 'heritage' architecture but it might suggest a particular fixed style. If you don't mind changing the parameters of your question, you can speak of a building *in keeping with the surrounding architecture*.

Comment: perhaps something like 'self-effacing' or 'harmonising'?

Comment: Uh… sorry. This is purely about personal choice of style.

If you first corrected the whole Question, it should become more obvious what word or phrase might fit your gap.

Comment: I would try 'background', 'routine', or 'standard', or maybe 'unadventurous'.

Answer (score 1):

The exact word you are looking for is **blending** (used as an adjective).

Definition of **to blend** (intr.): "To be unobtrusive or harmonious by resembling the surroundings or behaving like others in a group." ([American Heritage](http://American%20Heritage), no. 2)

See an example described as [blending architecture](https://architizer.com/projects/blending-architecture/).

Answer (score 0):

"settling on **trite** traditionalism for good"

> TRITE: hackneyed or boring from much use : not fresh or original

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trite